# Using a query string of /?value instead of /?key=value

Tags: php

I know the format for a query string is a *key* => *value* format like `/?key=rob`.

I am wondering if it is possible just to make the query string like `/?rob`, and I could still set `$_SESSION['username']` to the name value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the request string sent with `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`. From there, you can take everything after the `?`:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = explode('?', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?: 'YOU')[1];
// rob
```

If there is no request URI, the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?: 'YOU'` sets it to the username `YOU`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    reset($_GET);
    $username=key($_GET);
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
}
?>
```

Comment: Non-`GET` methods can have query strings, too.